# Unable to locate package

Tags: apt, kali-linux

After Upgrading my Current operating System Kali to Kali Version to 2017.2 .unable to install any software with
`sudo apt-get install<package name>`

what i a have done

i used the

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

and after Upgrading

i am getting error as

```
E:Unable to Locate package
```

tried to upgrade again but it is doing the same

i changed the repo(Resaved the content from the repo of kali linux rolling) details also doing the same
but it is continuing the same thing

after that i have done
as the following

`apt update ; apt full-upgrade -y ; apt autoremove -y`

It's telling me to fix broken
by `apt --fix-broken install`

when i tried to install the broken links it is giving error as

```
root@Pavan:~# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-data apache2-utils castxml chrome-gnome-shell espeak-data fakeroot
  firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc gccxml gdebi-core
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-2.0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 git-man
  gnome-characters gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-logs gnome-mime-data
  gnupg-agent gnuplot-tex gnuplot5-data gnuplot5-qt gstreamer1.0-packagekit
  hwdata imagemagick-common iproute java-wrappers libadns1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasn1-8-heimdal
  libbasicusageenvironment0 libbind9-90 libblas-common libbonobo2-0
  libbonobo2-common libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libboost-python1.58.0
  libboost-system1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0 libcamel-1.2-54 libchromaprint0
  libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libconfig9 libcrypto++6 libcrypto++9v5
  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libdns100 libebook-1.2-16 libedataserver-1.2-21 libespeak1
  libevent-core-2.0-5 libevent-openssl-2.0-5 libevent-pthreads-2.0-5
  libfakeroot libgadu3 libgdict-1.0-9 libgdict-common libgeos-3.5.0
  libgfortran3 libgif4 libgles1-mesa libglew1.13 libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra
  libgrilo-0.2-1 libgroupsock1 libgssapi3-heimdal libgtkglext1 libgtop-2.0-10
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libhdb9-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhunspell-1.3-0 libhx509-5-heimdal libical1a
  libilmbase6v5 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libjasper1
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjim0.76 libjpeg9 libjs-mochikit
  libkdc2-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libladr4 liblircclient0 liblivemedia23
  libllvm3.7 liblouis9 liblua5.1-0 liblwres90 libmeanwhile1 libmimic0
  libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-gtk-common libntdb1 libonig2 libopencv-contrib2.4v5
  libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopenexr6v5 liborbit-2-0
  libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libpcre16-3 libpng12-0 libpoppler57
  libpotrace0 libprotobuf-c1 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
  libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libptexenc1 libpth20 libpython-all-dev
  libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib libqdbm14 libqgsttools-p1
  libqmi-glib1 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediawidgets5
  libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libradare2-0.9.9 libregfi0 libroken18-heimdal
  libsynctex1 libtexlua52 libtexluajit2 libtracker-control-1.0-0
  libtracker-miner-1.0-0 libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 libtrio2 libtsk13
  libunistring0 liburcu4 libusageenvironment1 libusbmuxd2 libvncclient1
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebpdemux1 libwebpmux1 libwebrtc-audio-processing-0
  libwildmidi1 libwind0-heimdal libwireshark6 libwiretap5 libwsutil6 libx86-1
  libxcb-composite0 libzephyr4 libzip2 libzzip-0-13 lmodern maltegoce nginx
  perl-openssl-defaults php-common php-mysql php5-cli php5-json php5-readline
  php7.0-common php7.0-mysql pidgin-data prover9 python-adns python-alembic
  python-all python-all-dev python-boltons python-bson python-bson-ext
  python-characteristic python-cheetah python-clamd python-cluster
  python-ctypeslib python-d2to1 python-dap python-darts-lib-utils-lru
  python-dbus-dev python-defusedxml python-distlib python-easygui python-ecdsa
  python-editor python-esmre python-formencode python-geoip2 python-geojson
  python-gitdb python-gridfs python-guess-language python-halberd
  python-icalendar python-ipaddr python-keyring python-keyrings.alt
  python-levenshtein python-lzma python-lzo python-markdown python-maxminddb
  python-metaconfig python-mpltoolkits.basemap python-msgpack
  python-ndg-httpsclient python-nltk python-ntdb python-opengl python-openid
  python-paste python-pastedeploy python-pastedeploy-tpl python-pastescript
  python-pdfminer python-phply python-pip python-pip-whl python-ply
  python-psutil python-pyatspi python-pybloomfiltermmap python-pycryptopp
  python-pygithub python-pymongo python-pymongo-ext python-pyotp python-pypdf
  python-pyqtgraph python-pyscard python-qrcode python-qt4-gl
  python-ruamel.ordereddict python-scgi python-secretstorage python-smmap
  python-smoke-zephyr python-soappy python-stopit python-svn python-tblib
  python-tempita python-tidylib python-tzlocal python-vulndb python-webkit
  python-wheel python-wstools python-xdot python3.4 python3.4-minimal
  read-edid rsync ruby-rainbow ruby-rexec ruby-snmp ruby2.2-dev
  system-config-printer t1utils tex-common u3-tool vim-gui-common vlc-nox
  vpnc-scripts
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnuplot-data vlc-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnuplot-data vlc-bin
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 107 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/295 kB of archives.
After this operation, 779 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 304842 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnuplot-data (5.0.7+dfsg1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/gnuplot/gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex', which is also in package gnuplot-tex 4.6.6-3
Preparing to unpack .../vlc-bin_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-bin (2.2.6-6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-bin_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/cvlc', which is also in package vlc-nox 2.2.1-5+b1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/vlc-bin_2.2.6-6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Some More Information About my Version

```
DISTRIB_ID=Kali
DISTRIB_RELEASE=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_CODENAME=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2017.2"
VERSION_ID="2017.2"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.kali.org/"
```

but issue doesnt resoved try to help me

thanks in advance

pavan

Comment: Show the output of **cat /etc/apt/sources.list**

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue in the following way.

Remove lists with force and verbose:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

then I tried to fix broken with:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and then removed unneccesary of 650MB files with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then finally:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `vlc-nox`, it is in the list of packages that are installed but no longer required.

Sadly, fix-broken is trying to install another vlc package, `vlc-bin` without removing the other ... so, remove `vlc-nox`, then run `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`.

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc-nox
```

As for the `E:Unable to Locate package`, without more output, impossible to say what is going on, please provide full output for that.

Comment: when i am using sudo apt-get remove vlc-nox it is saying that                                          root@Pavan~# sudo apt-get remove vlc-nox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnuplot-qt : Depends: gnuplot-data (= 5.0.7+dfsg1-1) but it is not going to be installed
Vlc :Depends: vlc-bin (= 2.2.6-6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages

Answer (score 0):

To delete the troublesome repository, start Software & Updates tool:

[image: Software & Updates Settings Ubuntu in 20.04]
<sub>(source: [i0.wp.com](https://i0.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/software-updates-settings-ubuntu-20-04.jpg?ssl=1))</sub>

Go to the Other Software tab and look for the repository in question. Highlight it and then click on Remove button to delete it from your system.

[image: Remove Ppa]
<sub>(source: [i1.wp.com](https://i1.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/remove-ppa.jpg?ssl=1))</sub>